# HTML 5 Ruby on Rails Server Side Events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

I am new to HTML5 and Rails. I am trying to learn server side events to use it in my project.I have some doubts.
Can I use SSE to send data whenever there is an update in database ? If possible how to go with it. Can the EM monitor  database directly?
Which one is the best event based server (mongrel/rainbow/thin/goliath or any other one)?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

A simple but hands on example of [SSE with Goliath](http://www.igvita.com/2011/08/26/server-sent-event-notifications-with-html5/) (and deploying to heroku).

How you generate events really depends on your app logic.